# How to return a widget from for loop having json data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I am having a problem to iterate for loop for a json index and i am expecting in return a widget from for loop. I have stored Json file data in "mydata" variable and json have 3 index. There are 17 questions in index 0 and there answers in index 2 respectively. I want to print them on a card in following order:
Card 1:
Question 1: "QUestion 1 data"
Ans: "Question 1 Answer"

Card 2:Question 2: "Question 2 data"
Ans : "Question 2 Answer"

Here is the JSON file data:

```
[
{
    "1": "Conjugation is facilitated by",
    "2": "Bacterial endospores function in",
    "3": "Pasteur's main achievements are the development of vaccines for diseases",
    "4": "Germ theory of disease was formulated by",
    "5": "The major locomotory structures in bacteria are",
    "6": "Plasmid is",
    "7": "Which of the following is a primary bacterial cell wall function",
    "8": "When flagella surround the whole cell, the condition is called",
    "9": "Bacterial membrane also contain enzyme for",
    "10": "Which of the following is not found in all bacteria is",
    "11": "Greater pathogenicity to bacteria and protection against phagocytosis is provided by",
    "12": "Mesosomes are internal extensions of the",
    "13": "Bacterial membrane differs from eukaryotic membrane in",
    "14": "Which one of following class of bacteria has the smallest size",
    "15": "Which of the following is present in both gram-positive and gram-negative cell walls",
    "16": "Gram negaive cell wall has",
    "17": "One of the following has flagella rarely"
},
{
    "1": {
        "a": "Capsule",
        "b": "Pili",
        "c": "Flagella",
        "d": "Both pili and flagella"
    },
    "2": {
        "a": "Reproduction",
        "b": "Protein synthesis",
        "c": "Survival",
        "d": "Stronge"
    },
    "3": {
        "a": "Cholera, rabies only",
        "b": "Anthrax, rabies only",
        "c": "Anthrax, fowl cholera and rabies",
        "d": "None of the above"
    },
    "4": {
        "a": "Antone Van Leeuwenhoek",
        "b": "Pasteur",
        "c": "Robert Koch",
        "d": "none of above"
    },
    "5": {
        "a": "Flagella",
        "b": "Pili",
        "c": "Both a and b",
        "d": "None of these"
    },
    "6": {
        "a": "Essential for bacterial growth and metabolism",
        "b": "Drug resistant having disease and insect resistant gene",
        "c": "Essential for bacterial growth only",
        "d": "All of above"
    },
    "7": {
        "a": "Transport",
        "b": "Support",
        "c": "Motility",
        "d": "Adhesion"
    },
    "8": {
        "a": "Peritrichous",
        "b": "Atrichous",
        "c": "Amphitrichous",
        "d": "None of above"
    },
    "9": {
        "a": "Respiration",
        "b": "Photosynthesis",
        "c": "Protein synthesis",
        "d": "None of the above"
    },
    "10": {
        "a": "Cell membrane",
        "b": "A nucleoid",
        "c": "Flygella",
        "d": "None of these"
    },
    "11": {
        "a": "Capsule",
        "b": "Slime",
        "c": "Cell wall",
        "d": "Mesosomes"
    },
    "12": {
        "a": "Cell wall",
        "b": "Cell membrane",
        "c": "Chromatin body",
        "d": "Capsule"
    },
    "13": {
        "a": "Lacking protein",
        "b": "Lacking lipids",
        "c": "Lacking polysaccharides",
        "d": "Lacking sterol i.e. cholesterol"
    },
    "14": {
        "a": "Bacillus subtilis",
        "b": "Mycoplasma",
        "c": "E-coli",
        "d": "Straptococci"
    },
    "15": {
        "a": "An outer membrane",
        "b": "Peptidoglycan",
        "c": "Techoic acid",
        "d": "Lipopolysaccharides"
    },
    "16": {
        "a": "Only lipids",
        "b": "Only protein",
        "c": "More lipids and less protein",
        "d": "Less lipids and more protein"
    },
    "17": {
        "a": "Diplobacilli",
        "b": "Spiral",
        "c": "Cocci",
        "d": "All of above"
    }
},
{
    "1": "Pili",
    "2": "Survival",
    "3": "None of the above",
    "4": "Robert Koch",
    "5": "Flagella",
    "6": "Drug resistant having disease and insect resistant gene",
    "7": "Support",
    "8": "Peritrichous",
    "9": "Respiration",
    "10": "Flygella",
    "11": "Slime",
    "12": "Cell membrane",
    "13": "Lacking sterol i.e. cholesterol",
    "14": "Mycoplasma",
    "15": "Peptidoglycan",
    "16": "More lipids and less protein",
    "17": "Cocci"
}
```

]

Here is my code:

```
   class ResultPage extends StatelessWidget {
  int marks;
  int i = 1;
  var mydata;
  var length;

  ResultPage(this.marks, this.mydata, this.length);

@override 
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FinalResultCard(marks: marks, mydata: mydata, length: length,); 
  }
}


class FinalResultCard extends StatefulWidget {
  int marks;
  int i = 1;
  var mydata;
  var length;

  FinalResultCard({Key key, this.length, this.mydata, this.marks} ) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FinalResultCardState createState() => _FinalResultCardState(length, mydata, marks);
}
class _FinalResultCardState extends State<FinalResultCard> {
   int marks;
  int i = 1;
  var mydata;
  var length;

  _FinalResultCardState(this.length, this.mydata, this.marks);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Appbar ")
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: 1,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
        for(int i = 1; i<length; i++){
        var data = mydata[0][i.toString()];
        }

     return Text(data);

    }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't what i am doing wrong here. 
Looking for help and thanks in advance.

Comment: I just updated the JSON code here. I am working with this format and it works for me on test pages.

Comment: I solved it with same json format.